# Q:geolocation position undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm using geolocation to get my own latitude and longitude,but the console always return undefined,btw when I clicking  the tiy geolocation toturial on w3chool the response is "Location information is unavailable".

```
var lati,lgi;
 if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
} else {
console.warn("Your browser don't support geoloction!");
}

function success(pos) {
console.log(pos);
var cr;
cr = pos.coords;
lati= cr.latitude;
lgi = cr.longitude;
console.log(lati+","+lgi);
}
function error(err) {
console.warn("ERROR(" + err.code + "): " + err.message);
}
```

updated:I use dark-sky api to get some weather JSON，the remaining code updated.

```
function getData() {
var userkey = "***my key***";
var site = "https://crossorigin.me/https://api.darksky.net/forecast/";
var reqstr = site + userkey + lati + "," + lgi;
console.log(reqstr);
var data;
$.getJSON(reqstr, function(result) {
  data = JSON.parse(result);
});
console.log(data.latitude);
}
getData();
```

Comment: `longitde` !== `longitude`

Comment: also, some browsers only allow geolocation on "trusted" sites i.e. `https://`, not `http://`, `http://localhost` and `file:///` (the last two I'm not sure about)

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks but now the console ouput is "ERROR(2): Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : Returned error code 400."

Comment: "now the console" ... really? by fixing a simple typo you get some bizarre error that has nothing to do with the question? - you don't use any google api's in the code in question, so clearly the error is because of code you haven't shown

Comment: @JaromandaX  I updated the rest code.But the lati and lgi is still undefined in console.

Comment: can you please show how the first (asyncrhonous) code relates to the last - I'm guessing you are trying to run the code incorrectly, but it's not clear - I would expect you run `getCode` inside `success` - but it doesn't look like you do

Comment: @JaromandaX I just use first code to get latitude and longitude.And use them as parameters to send to dark-sky api to get the current weather JSON response.

Comment: as I added to the previous comment - I would expect you run `getCode` inside `success` - but it doesn't look like you do - `lati` and `lgi` are undefined until `success` is called

Comment: `getCurrentPosition()` is **asynchronous** ... you can't call `getData()` until the postion is receieved...no more than you can eat a pizza before it gets delivered

Comment: @JaromandaX @charlietfl I put `getData()` inside the `success` now the console ouput is just **"ERROR(2): Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : Returned error code 400."** the `console.log(reqstr);` don't work any more.I think it's because I'm in china and CCP blocked the geolocation service for somehow.

Comment: your request will be something like `https://crossorigin.me/https://api.darksky.net/forecast/***my key***12.34,56.78` - does that look right to you at all?

Comment: looking at the API documentation - you are missing a `/` ... `https://crossorigin.me/https://api.darksky.net/forecast/***m‌​y key***/12.34,56.78` ... i.e. `var reqstr = site + userkey + "/" + lati + "," + lgi;` ... which would explain the "bad request" error status

Comment: @JaromandaX yes,but the postion were nerver got.As I mentioned the geolocation example on w3school also don't work for me.

Comment: so, the initial problem hasn't been resolved - why are you even trying to get a forecast if you don't have lat/long yet!!! how is **your** web page hosted? what protocol is your page being loaded (http https file) ... what browser are you using?